# US state outlines not appearing in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think I'm struggling with a fairly simple problem, but I'm failing to either solve it myself or find a post that may have a solution. I'm plotting the USA and then adding points to map. However, when I plot the map the outlines for the stats do not appear. Any suggestions? Perhaps the path I've wondered down and I'm not using the appropriate map? Code below. Thanks in advance for the help and advice.

```
study2 <- c("ABQ", "ATL", "BUF", "CHS", "DEN", "MEM", "ORF", "Apker", "Apker", "Drewry", "Gardner", "Gould", "Gould", "Gould", "Hooker", "Sun", "Tredick", "Tredick", "Tredick", "Wilton") #city and study labels
lat2 <- c(35.5, 33.44, 42.52, 32.53, 39.44, 35.9, 36.50, 37.18, 39.7, 33.23, 44.1, 36.1, 35.6, 33.4, 32.3, 41.8, 36.31, 36, 36, 36.3)

long2 <- c(-106.36, -84.23, -78.52, -80.10, -104.59, -90.2, -76.17, -104.55, -107.51, -79.12, -75.45, -105.19, -106.23, -105.42, -83.3, -77.48, -76.27, -76.29, -76, -92.51)

elev.df2 <- data.frame(study2, lat2, long2)

shape2 <- c(15, 1, 19, 17, 2, 0, 18, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)

states <- map_data("state")


uv.map <- ggplot() + 

          coord_fixed() +

  geom_polygon(data = states, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "gray90") +

  geom_point(data = elev.df2, 
             aes(x = long2, y = lat2), 
             shape = shape2, 
             col = "black", 
             size = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)) +

  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", title = "") +

  theme_bw() +

  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +

  coord_equal(ratio=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The state boundaries are drawn using the `color=` parameter of the `geom_polygon`. Just set it to whatever color you want

```
geom_polygon(data = states, 
    aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
    fill = "gray90", 
    color="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick. It was as simple as I thought it would be. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: but…but… `coord_map("polyconic")` :-)